# Jquery FormData limitation

Tags: jquery, ajax

Using FormData and jquery i am sending a lot of inputs using ajax but not all of them are coming trough.

If i look in developer tools (Chrome) i am seeing something like:

```
1
------WebKitFormBoundaryGBYjXeMfAVtlYyAq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="position[660]"

15
------WebKitFormBoundaryGBYjXeMfAVtlYyAq--
```

So clearly the data is cut off.

Is there a limitation in the amount of data i can use with formdata and ajax?

The form works great with a small number of inputs, but with about 800 inputs it doesn't.

Thanks

Comment: Are you submitting using GET or POST?  I believe there is a URL character limit of around 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i need to increase max_input_vars value in php.ini